# why does accessing a property of a boolean value not throw an error - javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does accessing `false.bar` not throw an error while `undefined.bar` does?

```js
var foo1 = false;
var foo2;
console.log(foo1.bar); // undefined
console.log(foo2.bar); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look around for "boxing", you'll find that many answers have already been written.

To sum it up, `Boolean`, `Number` and `String` instances will magically "box" primitive values in a context where you're treating them as objects. Booleans don't have any useful methods or properties except the default Object-inherited ones, so you'll never see boolean boxing. But the language allows it.

However, there are no `Null` or `Undefined` constructors to box those values, so trying to access properties of `null` and `undefined` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, foo1 actually exists, so we can check for a property on it (it has no property defined called "bar", so we get a undefined for that).

The other case, foo2, doesnt exists (it never has been init and is still undefined), so trying to check for a property will result in a error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `false` itself is an object, while `undefined` isn't.

Variable is `undefined` if it wasn't assigned a value yet, like `foo2` in your code. You're trying to access a property of something that doesn't exist, so JS gets scared and throws error.

When you're trying to access `foo1`, the object `foo1` exists, since you've assigned `false` to it. JS doesn't mind that this object doesn't have a "bar" property and will just return `undefined`, as in "this property isn't defined yet".